# How to Count Results of Measure in a Table in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a measure "Classification" that classifies vendors by soled items. The table looks something like this:

| Vendor | Soled | Classification |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ven1 | 10 | B |
| Ven2 | 5 | C |
| Ven3 | 100 | A |
| Ven4 | 15 | B |

I am trying to build this table by counting the vendors fitting the Classification Measure:

| CountClass | Classification |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 1 | C |

But when I put the "Classification" Measure in a Table and make a Count on Vendor on the visualization I get this result:

| Vendor | Classification |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | A |

It just sums the vendors up and only shows the "Classification" = A. If I do not set a count on vendors, I can see all Classifications.

Here is how I calculate the "Classification":

```
Classification = 
SWITCH(TRUE(),
    SUMX(SalesTable, SalesTable[Soled_ALLPREV]) >= [Soled ALL A CutOff],"A",
    SUMX(SalesTable, SalesTable[Soled_ALLPREV]) >= [Soled ALL B CutOff]
    && SUMX(SalesTable, SalesTable[Soled_ALLPREV]) < [Soled ALL A CutOff],"B",
    SUMX(SalesTable, SalesTable[Soled_ALLPREV]) >= [Soled ALL C CutOff]
    && SUMX(SalesTable, SalesTable[Soled_ALLPREV]) < [Soled ALL B CutOff],"C",
    SUMX(SalesTable, SalesTable[Soled_ALLPREV]) >= [Soled ALL D CutOff]
    && SUMX(SalesTable, SalesTable[Soled_ALLPREV]) < [Soled ALL C CutOff],"D",
    "N/A")
```

This how it looks:
[image]

If I sum up on Vendor or use the suggested Measure

```
Measure 2 = calculate(countrows(VALUES(table[Vendor])))
```

The Calssification Measure still only shows "A" only:
[image]

The **problem** seams to be that I **want to use only measures on visuals** and this needs some level of detail otherwhise it just sums up. I belive that my Classification measure is the one that needs to be able to calculate also without other columns in the visual.

How can I make this work? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

THIS work for classification as COLUMN:

Create a simple measure:

```
CountOf: calculate(countrows(VALUES(table[Vendor])))
```

[image]

https://dax.guide/countrows/

EDIT:

Classification as measure.
Add additional unconnected table "class_label" as:

[image]

Add another measure:

```
Tst = if(SELECTEDVALUE(class_label[Classification]) = [Classification_mesure], clas[CountOf], 0)
```

Use these new objects together.

[image]

Comment: I test this on your data and its works correctly. Check it one more time.

Comment: sorry i overlooked that classification is a measure. Check my edited answer;

Comment: clas[CountOf] is your measure right?

Comment: Then my new measure would look like this:
Tst = if(SELECTEDVALUE(Class[Class]) = [Class_Booth_Space_ALL], _Measures[CountOf], 0)
With "SELECTEDVALUE" from my new ABC Class Table, [Class_Booth_Space_ALL] is my ABC calculating Measure and _Measures[CountOf] is the Measure you posted at the begining.
This Measure results in a 0.

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241490/power-bi
I created a stackoverflow chatroom if you would like to join